# Scrollbar apenas com botões ou div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Olá, preciso criar dois botões que tem como função a mesma de um scroll, porém sem barra, quero que ao clicar e segura o botão desça a página, e ao dar apenas um click, desça a página aos poucos.

O mesmo deve ser feito em javascript podendo usar no máximo um JQuery.

Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Segue o protótipo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Aparecida Nutrição</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        </head>
        <body>

            <header>
                <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="teste">Aparecida Nutrição</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div><div>
            <main>
                <button id="up">Up</button>
                <button id="down">Down</button>
                <section style="overflow: auto; height: 300px;" class="container">
                    <h2>Meus pacientes</h2>
                    <href class="scroll"/>
                    <table >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nome</th>
                                <th>Peso(kg)</th>
                                <th>Altura(m)</th>
                                <th>Gordura Corporal(%)</th>
                                <th>IMC</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="paciente" >
                                <td class="info-nome">Paulo</td>
                                <td class="info-peso">100</td>
                                <td class="info-altura">2.00</td>
                                <td class="info-gordura">10</td>
                                <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="paciente" >
                                <td class="info-nome">João</td>
                                <td class="info-peso">80</td>
                                <td class="info-altura">1.72</td>
                                <td class="info-gordura">40</td>
                                <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="paciente" >
                                <td class="info-nome">Erica</td>
                                <td class="info-peso">54</td>
                                <td class="info-altura">1.64</td>
                                <td class="info-gordura">14</td>
                                <td class="info-imc">0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>

            </section>
        </main>
        <script src="js/calcula-imc.js"></script>
        <script src="js/form.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Abaixo o javascript(tenho esses dois botões para trabalhar com o scroll up e down):

```
var up = document.getElementById("#up");
var down = document.getElementById("#down");
```

Tenho essas funções para usar:

```
up.addEventListener("click", function (event){

});

down.addEventListener("click", function (event){

});
```

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e coloca o que vc tem de código, assim fica mais fácil pra te responder, só com a imagem não da para te ajudar muito

Comment: assim já ajuda?

Comment: Sim agora a comunidade tem que votar para reabrir-la

Comment: @MatheusBerns veja se esse código http://jsfiddle.net/s5mgX/1709/ ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `window.scrollBy(a, b)`

Que recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro é a medida em pixels para a rolagem horizontal e o segundo a rolagem vertical.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  height: 7500px;
  width: 5000px;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 300px
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>conteúdo aqui</h3>

<button onclick="scrollWin(0, 50)">Descer</button><br><br>

<button onclick="scrollWin(0, -50)">Subir</button><br><br>

<button onclick="scrollWin(100, 0)">Direita</button><br><br>

<button onclick="scrollWin(-100, 0)">Esquerda</button><br><br>

<script>
function scrollWin(x, y) {
  window.scrollBy(x, y);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

fonte: [Desloca o documento dentro da janela pelo valor fornecido.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy)

Comment: Opa, caramba não sabia que existia uma forma tão simples de fazer isso, ajudou muito. Tinha deixado de lado essa função por enquanto, mas agora vou implementá-la, valeu!!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou @MatheusBerns!